# Nav menu from plugin to theme

Tags: php, menus

I would to take nav menu reference (I have id and class) from plugin to theme header.php...How can I do this?
I used something like this`<?php wp_nav_menu('id'); ?>` but of course with failure cause I didn't specific from where I pick this menu...How can I do?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I want bring menu function from plugin to theme and use it.

Answer (score 1):

**wp_nav_menu()** doesn't accept a single value for a parameter, it takes an array. Proper format (if you are looking to simply call the menu by ID) would look like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu' => $menu_id
    )
);
```

I'd recommend checking out the [full reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) in the codex for more information on the available parameters for displaying a menu.

Comment: Will it recognize menu from plugin directory?

Comment: What do you mean by this? What "plugin directory" are you referring to?